# Drop-Down Menu with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I'm working on an **Drop-Down Menu** but without success.
I want the same function like the Drop-Down menu by [Sony](http://www.sony.de/).I have even tried to imitate this effect, but I had a few difficulties.

My HTML:

```
<div id="main_menu">
<div id="main_menu_container">
    <div id="main_menu_links">
        <a href="" class="main_menu_link">Startseite</a>
        <a id="drop_down_link1" class="main_menu_link">Events</a>
        <a id="drop_down_link2" class="main_menu_link">Clan</a>
        <a id="drop_down_link3" class="main_menu_link">Irgendetwas</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="drop_down_container">
    <div id="drop_down_content1" class="drop_down_content"></div>
    <div id="drop_down_content2" class="drop_down_content"></div>
    <div id="drop_down_content3" class="drop_down_content"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#drop_down_link1").mouseenter(function (){
    $("#drop_down_content1").stop().slideDown();
});
$("#drop_down_content1, #drop_down_link1").mouseleave(function (){
    $("#drop_down_content1").delay(350).slideUp();
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/epsm3/)**

The problem in my script is, when i leave drop_down_link1 or drop_down_content1 then the 
content 'slideUp' but when i hover from drop_down_link1 to drop_down_content1 then there shouldn't be the function.

So my question is:

1. How can I do this that I can move between the link and the 'content' with my mouse without 'content' close?
2. My code is very unprofessional. How do I make it so that I do not repeat myself when 'Events' and 'Clan' have the same function?

Comment: Firstly this could be done using css but if you go down a route of .toggleClass jquery could be of some use. Let me have a look

Comment: I really would do this rather with css and transition than with javascript. But if you want, just change your selector to $("#drop_down_link1, #drop_down_content1").mouseenter....

Comment: But i need a JS or jQuery solution :(

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/PKvZ2/

Try with this code. I added  :

```
$("#drop_down_link1,#drop_down_container").mouseenter(function (){
    $("#drop_down_content1").stop().slideDown();
});
$("#drop_down_content1, #drop_down_link1,#drop_down_container").mouseleave(function (){
    $("#drop_down_content1").delay(350).stop().slideUp();
});
```

Or this

```
$("#drop_down_link1,#drop_down_container").hover(function (){
    $("#drop_down_content1").stop().slideDown();
},function(){
        $("#drop_down_content1").stop().slideUp();

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bT8Cp/

Comment: well can u do the second question, because i want the same function to 'Events' and 'Clan'

Comment: You wanna write proffesional code ? I understand  your question like this. Get books about good practice or  read at the net.
And with the practice you will see how  you can  do it more clean and cleaver. I'm senior php , and I rewrite old systems, and you cant belive what code I must  read every day and repair it...

Comment: i've mean that my code looks unprofessional and i ask how to do it right that i can use the other dropdown links...

Answer (score 0):

Very simple! Just handle both `#drop_down_link1` and `#drop_down_content1` mouseenter events as follows

```
    $("#drop_down_link1,#drop_down_content1").mouseenter(function (){
       $("#drop_down_content1").stop().slideDown();
     });
   $("#drop_down_content1, #drop_down_link1").mouseleave(function (){
      $("#drop_down_content1").delay(350).stop().slideUp();
    });
```

2.

```
   $('#main_menu_container a.main_menu_link').each(function(index,item){
      alert(index);
      var $this=$(this),
          $dropdownContent=$('#drop_down_container .drop_down_content')
      [index];

     ......

  });
```

Comment: and the second question i want the same function in events and in clan and i dont repeat me :( PS: your link to fiddle is wrong

Comment: The problem with the above, it that for every nav, selfproblemmade would have to re-create this code and add an extra numerical digit. To both a nav element and container element.

Comment: jes, and thats why i dont want to repeat my self, it looks unprofessional.